# Why does Gradle ignore sourceSets and/or srcDir when dealing with proto files?

Tags: gradle, protocol-buffers

My directory structure is src/ps/proto.   My build.gradle file is located in the src directory.  I've set sourceSets to

```
sourceSets {
    ps {
        proto {
             srcDir 'ps/proto'
        }
    }
}
```

Yet, a **gradlew generatePsProto** gives me a slew of error, one of which is that my source directory is **src/src/ps/proto**.

```
Execution failed for task ':generatePsProto'.
> protoc: stdout: . stderr: /home/build/tree/src/src/ps/proto: warning: directory does not exist.
  [libprotobuf WARNING google/protobuf/compiler/parser.cc:546] No syntax specified for the proto file: cldb.proto. Please use 'syntax = "proto2";' or 'syntax = "proto3";' to specify a syntax version. (Defaulted to proto2 syntax.)
  ps/proto/security.proto: File not found.
  ps/proto/common.proto: File not found.
  ps/proto/cli.proto: File not found.
  ps/proto/volumemirrorcommon.proto: File not found.
  ps/proto/metrics.proto: File not found.
  cldb.proto: Import "ps/proto/security.proto" was not found or had errors.
  cldb.proto: Import "ps/proto/common.proto" was not found or had errors.
  mldb.proto: Import "ps/proto/cli.proto" was not found or had errors.
  mldb.proto:214:12: "CredentialsMsg" is not defined.
  mldb.proto:218:12: "CredentialsMsg" is not defined.
  [...]
  mldb.proto:3614:12: "Key" is not defined.
  mldb.proto:3618:12: "CredentialsMsg" is not defined.
  mldb.proto:3619:12: "ServerKeyType" is not defined.
```

I don't want the Gradle default of src/ps/proto.  I want ps/proto.  Can this be done?  My goal is to remove the hard coded exec calls to protoc and use the protobuf pluging to compile the *.proto files into their respective *.h, *.cc, and eventually into *.o files.

> Gradle 4.7 Build time:   2018-04-18 09:09:12 UTC Revision:
>   b9a962bf70638332300e7f810689cb2febbd4a6c
>
> Groovy:       2.4.12 Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.9
>   compiled on February 2 2017 JVM:          1.8.0_144 (Oracle
>   Corporation 25.144-b01) OS:           Linux 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64
>   amd64

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.5'
    }
}


apply plugin: 'c'
apply plugin: 'cpp'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.4.1"
}


sourceSets {
    ps {
        proto {
            srcDir 'ps/proto'
        }
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:2.4.1'
    }

    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.plugins {
                cpp {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seemed to have typo either for 'fs' or 'ps'.

The problem is the Import.
because you have for example

cldb.proto: Import "ps/proto/security.proto"

mldb.proto: Import "ps/proto/cli.proto"

**Edited:**

you have to put every .proto file in src/yourCustomSourceSetName/proto/ps/proto/ and add

```
sourceSets {
    yourCustomSourceSetName {}
}
dependencies {
    compile ...  // dependencies for compileJava task
    yourCustomSourceSetNameCompile ... // dependencies for custom sourceSet
    compile sourceSets.yourCustomSourceSetName.output // compileJava uses output of the custom sourceSet
}
```

Then the import will look for other .proto files in the right place.

Comment: 'ps' is the custom source set name.   Unfortunately, trimming the SourceSets as you suggested, I'm still getting /home/build/tree/src/src/ps/proto.  I'm unable to rid myself of the second 'src'.

Comment: if 'ps' is the custom source set name, you should put every .proto file in **src/ps/proto/ps/proto/**, then the import can look into the right place. Just `SourceSets { ps {} }` would be enough, no need to add `proto { srcDirs = [ ...] }` inside it.

Comment: Trying the above suggestion did clear up the errors and did created a build directory, but the build/extracted-protos/ps and build/extracted-include-protos/ps directories were empty.

Comment: It's normal that build/extracted-* is empty. Is your `build/generated/` directory empty?

Comment: Yes, the build/generated is empty too.

Comment: oh, I just saw you have `generatedFilesBaseDir = "$projectDir/build/ps/proto"` in your build.gradle, that means you should check whether `build/ps/proto/` contains the generated files rather than `build/generated`

Comment: I knew to check that directory.  It's empty too.

Comment: I tried **./gradlew generatePsProto** on myside (with a different set of .proto files though), it did generate successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle has a widely applicable convention that collection properties can be configured with methods of the same name. The key difference between setting a property using assignment (`=`) and using a method is that the latter *appends* its values.

So, to override the default source directory for the source set you need to use assignment:

```
sourceSets {
    ps {
        proto {
            srcDirs = ['ps/proto']
        }
    }
}
```

I don't really understand why you're getting an error message about *src/src/ps/proto*, so there may be some other issue. That error seems to be coming from `protoc` rather than Gradle.

**EDIT**

To solve your import problem, you should use

```
import security.proto;
```

i.e. without the source directory path. This is because the Protobuf Gradle Plugin appears to add each source directory as an "include directory". `protoc` *only* looks in such include directories for imports.

This is at least what I have garnered from the documentation and source code.

Comment: Cutting-n-Pasting the sourceSets removed the src/src/... error, but the "ps/proto/<filename>.proto: File not found" errors remained.

Comment: Perhaps your import statements are incorrect. Do they include _ps/proto/_ in their paths? If so, you probably shouldn't include the source directory path in the import. Just guessing though.

Comment: Currently, the ps/proto directory is successfully built via SCons, which contains hard coded calls to /usr/local/protobuf-2.4.1/.   The goal here to convert from the slow antiquated SCons to Gradle, which is quick.  The source tree does build.  I want the tree to build Gradle.